# Network Analyst not creating all junctions

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, snapping, arcgis-10.5

I have a road network that I have added and merged with a KML into a shapefile that I'm trying to create a network with. However, when I build the network, I receive errors "The features's geometry has zero length" and "The edge feature is too small to participate in snapping and may not be connected to other features"

Then upon further inspection after the network has been built, I see that I'm missing many junctions where there was the existing road network and where I merged the KML with the street network. I'm not too sure how to fix this. Attached are some screenshots.The dot not on the line segment is just from another layer I forgot to turn off.[image: Summary]

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: relevant? http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000009992

Answer (score 1):

The rebuild connectivity tool incrementally rebuilds the connectivity between edges and junctions in the network in a small area.  The connectivity tool can be used to repair any local inconsistency between geometry and network connectivity within a small area.  The tool will identify and repair several types of connectivity errors such as a network junction that is not coincident with edges to which it is connected, a network element associated with a zero length edge or a network with invalid edge element order. This command creates a new orphan junction at the endpoint of edges where junctions were missing.  To correct junctions, go to the ArcMap table of contents, select one of the feature classes that participates in the geometric network containing the failed junctions and click the Network Rebuild Errors command to identify failed features and locate the standalone junction to correct.  The junctions can be fixed by by deleting the junction and connecting the junction to the preferred feature edge.  Junctions connect to edges at endpoints or vertices depending on the target edge source's connectivity policy.